# Symfony 4 Fixture with relationship

Tags: php, symfony, relational-database, fixtures

I'm finally trying Symfony after a long time with Laravel, and I'm doing the classic learning project for when I try a new piece of software, a blog.

Now I need some dummy content for the articles so I'm trying fixtures, the problem is, I already have a user in the database and every new article is obviously related to a user, BUT if I try to fetch the user inside the fixture using the fixture's manager:

```
$user = $manager->find('User', 1);
```

it returns

```
In MappingException.php line 96:

  Class 'User' does not exist
```

I guess because the fixture manager is different from EntityManager.

So how can I tell my fixture to add a relationship with the first user for every actile it creates?

Here's my fixture code :

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {

        $user = $manager->find('User', 1);
        for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $article = new Article();
        // Random word title
        $word = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'));
        shuffle($word);
        $word = substr(implode($word), 0, 20);
        $article->setName = $word;
        $article->setSlug = $this->slugify($word);
        $article->setContent = " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur neque augue, dictum a tortor sed, tempus tristique magna. Mauris sed libero lacinia, suscipit urna sit amet, vulputate lorem. Donec non aliquet nibh. Integer feugiat arcu lacus, vel tempor est blandit eu. Proin congue purus quam, ac efficitur enim suscipit et. Vivamus vehicula lectus et dolor mollis bibendum. Praesent dignissim ligula sed neque sodales, quis volutpat nisl tempus. In efficitur erat id orci ultricies viverra. Nunc scelerisque mi quis est efficitur, et fringilla sem porta. Praesent non lorem efficitur, iaculis tortor et, finibus sem. Nam ornare dictum placerat. Nunc mi massa, iaculis at mattis non, luctus id ipsum. Ut ut auctor dolor. Nulla imperdiet, tortor ut egestas commodo, libero tortor fermentum massa, vitae fermentum lorem elit a velit. In sit amet malesuada eros. Ut bibendum luctus nunc, non posuere nulla fringilla et. Suspendisse fermentum risus eu nibh ornare, in placerat enim iaculis. Quisque vestibulum justo nec nibh molestie rutrum. In volutpat pretium justo quis sollicitudin. Cras eu vulputate nulla. Integer at dolor luctus, consequat ante id, suscipit dolor. Vestibulum ante augue, semper at suscipit nec, condimentum at quam. Phasellus sollicitudin sagittis dolor ut cursus. Duis nunc urna, molestie ac lacus a, molestie pharetra justo. ";

        $article->setDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $article->setStatus = "published";
        $article->setLikes = 0;
        $article->setCommentsCount = 0;
        $article->setCreated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $article->setUpdated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $article->setUser = $user;
        $manager->persist($article);

        $manager->flush();
    } // end for
    } // end load function
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO The error comes from the syntax, try that

```
$user = manager->getRepository('YourBundle:User')->find(1);
```